# In this widget with 3 listeners, how is Flutter handling the multiple listeners?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I followed the docs on how to create a Realtime Database listener and implemented what you see below. The 1st listener gets all the groups that the user is a part of, so this is just a basic listener at a given user node.

However, the 2nd and 3rd listeners are different. These listeners require an input groupID that is used to build the ref to the specific node where it needs to listen to.

When the user gets to this screen, the `initialize()` function runs `getGroupsListener()` and assigns the listener to the `groupsListener` variable. Later, when this screen is closed, this listener is disposed of with `groupsListener.cancel()` in `dispose()`.

For the other 2 listeners, I need help understanding what is happening here. Right now, this setup works - my app can retrieve new children added to the group chat nodes and the last read timestamp. But how does this work if this screen is using 1 variable to store a listener to multiple groups? And then would it correctly cancel the listeners when the user leaves the screen, i.e. when the `dispose()` function runs?

```
var groupsListener;
var lastReadTimestampListener;
var groupChatListener;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  initialize();
}

void initialize() async {
  getGroupsListener();
}

@override
dispose() {
  groupsListener.cancel();
  groupChatListener.cancel();
  lastReadTimestampListener.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}

//Get the list of groups that the user is a part of:
  void getGroupsListener() async {
    await globals.userGlobals(); //Required if using globals
    groupsStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(globals.usersCollection).doc(globals.currentUID).collection(globals.groupsCollection).snapshots();

    groupsListener = groupsStream.listen((event) {
      tempGroupsList = [];

      for (var doc in event.docs) {
        tempGroupsList.add(doc.data());
      }

      tempGroupsList.forEach((element) {
        final group = ModelGroup.fromJson(element);
        getLastReadTimestampListener(group.groupID);
        getGroupChatsListener(group.groupID);
      });

      setState(() {
        //update the UI...
      });
    });
  }


//Gets all the chats in a given group:
  void getGroupChatsListener(String groupID) async {
    await globals.userGlobals(); //Required if using globals

    if (groupID == '') {
      return;
    }

    final node = globals.groupChatsNode(groupID);

    DatabaseReference groupChatRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(node);

    groupChatListener = groupChatRef.onValue.listen((event) {
      final data = event.snapshot.value;
    });

    setState(() {
      //update the UI...
    });
  }


//Gets a single value per group ID that represents the timestamp of the latest chat the current user has read:
  void getLastReadTimestampListener(String groupID) async {
    await globals.userGlobals(); //Required if using globals

    if (groupID == '') {
      return;
    }

    final node = globals.groupActivityNode(groupID);

    DatabaseReference groupActivityRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(node);

    lastReadTimestampListener = groupActivityRef.onValue.listen((event) {
      final data = event.snapshot.value;
    });

    setState(() {
      //update the UI...
    });
  }
```